# example in spectral theory

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, compact-operators, adjoint-operators

Consider $X=l_{2}.$ Let $T : l_{2}\longrightarrow l_{2}$ be defined by :
$T(x_{1},x_{2},....)= (x_{1},\frac{x_{2}}{2},\frac{x_{3}}{3},...).$ And $S=I$ , the identity operator. Here $N(T)=N(S)=\lbrace{0\rbrace}.$ Suppose that $T$ majorizes $I.$ Then $T$ has a closed range, a contradiction.
I have two questions :

1. Why R(T) is closed ?
2. what is the contradiction?

**i need help please**

Answer (score 0):

It $T\geq I$, then $T$ is bounded below and this implies closed range.

In your setting that's a contradiction because $T$ is compact, and a compact operator only has closed range when its range is finite-dimensional. For your concrete case $T$ has dense range, so if its range would be close, it would be surjective (which it isn't).

Comment: Thank you very much sir, it's clear now. Just for the density of $R(T)$ in $l_{2}$, to show it , is it necessary to take an element $x$ in $l_{2},$ and build a sequence $x_{n}$ in $R(T)$ such that $x_{n}$ converge to $x$ ??

Comment: @Mathsforever: the range of $T$ contains the canonical basis.

Comment: I understand thank you, but I don't see why $T$ isn't surjective

Comment: Find $x$ with $Tx=(1,\tfrac12,\tfrac13,\ldots)$.

Comment: x=(1,1,1......) ! and $x \notin l_{2}$ because $(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1)^{\frac{1}{2}} = +\infty$